# Getting an error running the simple initialised app in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I've created the simple intitialised app via:

```
react-native init myApp
```

It creates it fine.  And when I run it with:

```
react-native run-android
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./Libraries/YellowBox/YellowBox` from `node_modules\react-native\index.js`:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.and....(continues)
```

The incredibly frustrating thing about this is that I've successfully run the initialised app (on previous initialisations) multiple times in the last few days.  So I don't know why it won't run today (tried three initialisations today).  I haven't changed the code one character from the intitialisation.  I've tried restarting my computer, deleting my virtual android device (via Android Studio) and creating a new one.  Still the same error keeps coming up. I've tried running it via my physical Android device, same error.  I've tried deleting the node-modules from the project and reinstalling them (`npm install`).  Same error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Commenting just to say that I am experiencing the same issue after re-installing dependencies - I'm using the out of the box typescript bare template from expo init.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it using this command:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

After start of the Metro run the app:

```
react-native run-android
```

> In my case it happened after updating a package.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue, found it to be a caching issue with metro.
YellowBox was moved to YellowBoxDeprecated.

I was able to fix this issue by doing the following:

- delete node_modules and package-lock.json
- clear metro-cache folder.(for windows default location is %appdata%\Local\Temp\metro-cache)
- clear gradle cache (`cd android & .\gradlew clean`)
- `npm install` the packages